# Secure Coding Guidelines

Tags: scala, secure-coding

There is

> Secure Coding Guidelines for the Java Programming Language
>   [Version 4.0](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/seccodeguide-139067.html)

Is there something similar for scala?

If not, can you suggest Scala specific ones?

Comment: I guess you could use this guidelines for `Java` with scala style guides. Some parts of Java Secure Coding Guidelines are not language specific, like `Avoid dynamic SQL`, some parts are the same as in style guide, like `Prefer immutability for value types`.

Comment: I completly agree. As a newcommer to scala, I wonder If there are some Scala specific issues to be aware of. Or if there are more elegant solutions? Are any of those idioms build in? You got the idea by now...

Comment: See this article: [Does Scala == Effective Java?](http://www.grahamlea.com/2013/12/does-scala-equal-effective-java/), it's not about security, but related. I can give you only one scala specific issues: you should note that some scala features exists only in compile time. For instance: from java one can create subclass of `sealed trait` or override `final def` of `trait`.